# A problem with proving the statement "if $X'X$ is nonsingular, $n \geq k$"

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

I had the following question: given X $[n*k]$, prove that if $X'X$ is nonsingular, $n \geq k$. I used the rank-nullity theorem and proved that $n$ has to be at least equal to $k$ for the full rank notion to hold. What I don't understand is the following:

How come $n$ may exceed $k$ and yet we can still consider the matrix $X$ full rank? I mean doesn't that lead to a situation where there aren't enough column vectors to occupy the full $n$-dimensional space?

My understanding and I am probably mistaken please excuse my lack of knowledge, is that if $n$ exceeds $k$, then it is impossible for $k$ to span a $k$-dimensional subspace that occupies the full $R^n$ space, and therefore, the notion of full rank is contradicted.

What am I misunderstanding? Could you please explain this to me?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Isn't your question really "what is the definition of full rank?" That is answered here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra) - in your case, full rank means rank $k$.

Comment: maybe I missed something there, thanks for the comment :D

Answer (score 1):

Take
$$X_{n\times k}=\begin{pmatrix}
I_k\\O
\end{pmatrix},$$
then
$$X^t\cdot X=I_k,$$
where $I$ is the identity matrix.

Please note that with $X_{n\times k}$, we have $(X^t\cdot X)_{k\times k}$.